Revit to NWC and NWD
I am trying to export revit model to NWC model and I have successfully done it. But only the thing now I am trying it further to convert nwc model into nwd model. For this I am applying the logic like after exporting the nwc model, I am trying to open the nwc file in currently installed navisworks.
But here I am stucked to save as nwd model. Can anyone please help me put for this ?
Below is my WIP code:
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Autodesk.Revit.Attributes;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI;

namespace XXXX
{
    [Transaction(TransactionMode.Manual)]
    public class NavisExporter : IExternalCommand
    {
        public Result Execute(
            ExternalCommandData commandData,
            ref string message,
            ElementSet elements)
        {
            // Get the active document
            Document document = commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument.Document;

            // Get the name of the active Revit document without the extension
            string documentName = document.Title;
            if (documentName.EndsWith(".rvt", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                documentName = documentName.Substring(0, documentName.Length - 4);
            }

            // Use FolderBrowserDialog to select folder
            string folder = string.Empty;
            using (FolderBrowserDialog folderDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog())
            {
                folderDialog.Description = "Select the folder to save the NWC file";
                if (folderDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    folder = folderDialog.SelectedPath;
                }
                else
                {
                    message = "No folder selected for export.";
                    return Result.Cancelled;
                }
            }

            // Name for the NWC file
            string name = documentName;

            bool exportLinks = false;
            bool exportElementIds = true;
            string navisCoordinates = "1"; // 0 for Internal Coordinates, 1 for Shared Coordinates
            bool exportUrls = false;
            View3D view3D = null;

            // Initialize Navisworks export options
            NavisworksExportOptions exportOptions = new NavisworksExportOptions
            {
                ExportLinks = exportLinks,
                ConvertElementProperties = false,
                FindMissingMaterials = true,
                ExportRoomAsAttribute = false,
                ExportElementIds = exportElementIds,
                ExportUrls = exportUrls,
                ExportRoomGeometry = false,
                Coordinates = (NavisworksCoordinates)int.Parse(navisCoordinates)
            };

            // Get the ViewFamilyType for 3D views
            ViewFamilyType viewFamilyType = new FilteredElementCollector(document)
                .OfClass(typeof(ViewFamilyType))
                .Cast<ViewFamilyType>()
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ViewFamily == ViewFamily.ThreeDimensional);

            // Start a transaction to create a 3D view
            using (Transaction transaction = new Transaction(document, "Create View"))
            {
                transaction.Start();
                View3D tempView3D = View3D.CreateIsometric(document, viewFamilyType.Id);

                // Get the phase filter "None" if available
                PhaseFilter nonePhaseFilter = new FilteredElementCollector(document)
                    .OfClass(typeof(PhaseFilter))
                    .Cast<PhaseFilter>()
                    .FirstOrDefault(pf => pf.Name == "None");

                if (nonePhaseFilter != null)
                {
                    tempView3D.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.VIEW_PHASE_FILTER).Set(nonePhaseFilter.Id);
                }

                // Set the view for export
                if (view3D == null)
                {
                    exportOptions.ViewId = tempView3D.Id;
                }
                else
                {
                    exportOptions.ViewId = view3D.Id;
                }

                transaction.Commit();

                try
                {
                    // Export the document to NWC
                    document.Export(folder, name, exportOptions);

                    // Launch Navisworks Manage
                    string nwcFilePath = Path.Combine(folder, name + ".nwc");
                    if (LaunchNavisworks(nwcFilePath, out string errorMessage))
                    {
                        TaskDialog.Show("Export Successful", $"Exported to {nwcFilePath} and launched Navisworks.");
                        return Result.Succeeded;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        message = errorMessage;
                        return Result.Failed;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    message = ex.Message;
                    return Result.Failed;
                }
            }
        }

        private bool LaunchNavisworks(string nwcFilePath, out string errorMessage)
        {
            try
            {
                string[] possiblePaths = new string[]
                {
                    @"C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Navisworks Manage 2024\Roamer.exe",
                    @"C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Navisworks Manage 2023\Roamer.exe",
                    @"C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Navisworks Manage 2022\Roamer.exe",
                    @"C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Navisworks Manage 2021\Roamer.exe",
                    @"C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Navisworks Manage 2020\Roamer.exe"
                };

                string navisworksPath = possiblePaths.FirstOrDefault(File.Exists);

                if (navisworksPath == null)
                {
                    errorMessage = "No valid Navisworks executable found !";
                    return false;
                }

                ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = navisworksPath,
                    Arguments = $"\"{nwcFilePath}\"",
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                };

                using (Process proc = Process.Start(start))
                {
                    proc.WaitForExit();
                    int exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
                    if (exitCode == 0)
                    {
                        errorMessage = null;
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        errorMessage = $"Navisworks exited with code {exitCode}.";
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errorMessage = "Error: " + ex.Message;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}

